# BizTalk SQL Server Job always fails after some hours

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2016

We have BizTalk 2016 running on SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn.

The SQL Server Agent Job `MessageBox_Message_ManageRefCountLog_BizTalkMsgBoxDb` is doing its thing but after some hours it fails. Sometimes 10 hours sometimes 90 hours or anything in between. I know, the job is designed to run forever and in a case of an error restarts itself within a minute. But I would like to know the actual error message for this failed job. The job history is not helpful because the job log entry is truncated.

[image: Job History]

A failover is not happening. The question is: WHY is this job failing and ultimately: how do I stop it from doing that?

---

I have set-up the extended monitoring of the failing step and it revealed, that the job failed because of a deadlock and it was chosen as the deadlock victim. So now is the question, why is there a deadlock? Is `MessageBox_Message_ManageRefCountLog_BizTalkMsgBoxDb`known for deadlock issues?

[image: Setup Sql Server Job for more history logging]

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server log to see if you have more information regarding the error there?

Comment: sql server log has nothing about this job and the windows eventviewer only tells me, that the job has failed but not why

Comment: Have you run BizTalk Health Monitor?

Comment: I recently did that, found 42 messages with negative refcount, let it fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation at [Description of the SQL Server Agent Jobs in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919776/description-of-the-sql-server-agent-jobs-in-biztalk-server), it says:

> Important At first, the MessageBox_Message_ManageRefCountLog_BizTalkMsgBoxDb job status icon displays a status of Success. However, **there will be no corresponding success entry in the job history**. If one of the jobs in the MessageBox_Message_ManageRefCountLog_BizTalkMsgBoxDb job fails, a failure entry appears in the job history and the status icon displays a status of Failure. **The job will always display a status of Failure after the first failure**. To verify that the other BizTalk Server SQL Server Agent jobs run correctly, check the status of the other BizTalk Server SQL Server Agent jobs.

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: I saw that doc. I am actually seeing too many failed jobs. Like every 1 to 3 days.